# How to enable Copy Paste for textview in Xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin.android, textview, android

I have RecyclerView, using ViewHolder contains CardView with TextView.
For the textview, I have enabled 'textIsSelectable' property which allows you to select text and copy it.
Below is my textview:

```
              <TextView
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtNFDescription"
                android:textColor="#3f4852"
                android:bufferType="spannable"
                android:textIsSelectable="true" />
```

It works for me if I land on this page for the first time.
But if i scroll up this recycler view 
OR
Navigate to another page and then land to the same page where i have this implementation. It stops working.

And OUTPUT window gives me this error when I longpress on textview after navigating or scrolling:

```
08-17 12:05:20.031 W/TextView(10128): TextView does not support text selection. Selection cancelled.
```

Any Suggestions or solutions why is this happening?